# Соединить несколько SQL запросов в 1

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

**Основная информация**

- Есть сайт на Wordpress.
- На сайте есть записи с заголовками формата "Алексей 0981178989 Ford
  Mondeo 2006 г.в."
- В папке /wp-content/uploads/2018/09/ есть изображения с именем номера
  телефона, то есть 0981178989.jpg
- Изображения отображаются в Медиафайлах, то есть имеют уникальный ID и
  имеют в БД тип поста attachment.
- Заголовок у изображений соответствует номеру телефона (в данном
  случае 0981178989)

---

**Что у нас есть**

**1.** У нас есть SQL запрос, которым мы получаем ID поста, в заголовке которого есть номер 0981178989

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%0981178989%' AND post_type = 'post'
```

**2.** У нас есть SQL запрос, которым мы получаем ID attachment (изображения 0981178989.jpg с post_type = 'attachment')

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%0981178989%' AND post_type = 'attachment'
```

---

**Что нам нужно**

В SQL запрос

```
UPDATE `DB_Name`.`wp_posts` SET `post_parent` = 'XXXXX' WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID` = YYYYY
```

вместо XXXXX вставить результат первого запроса (цифровое значение)

вместо YYYYY вставить результат второго запроса (цифровое значение)

Comment: все можно сделать через под запросы

Comment: `UPDATE таблица, (первый подзапрос), (второй подзапрос) SET ...` хотя всё можно и в один подзапрос затолкать.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
UPDATE `DB_Name`.`wp_posts`
SET `post_parent` = (SELECT
    ID
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE post_title LIKE '%0981178989%'
  AND post_type = 'post')
WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID` = (SELECT
    ID
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE post_title LIKE '%0981178989%'
  AND post_type = 'attachment');
```